# How to force Grails Resource plugin load right after application started

Tags: grails, plugins, embedded-resource, grails-plugin

In my Grails project, I use the Resource plugin to control and manage all resource files in application.
Its is embedded to my project like this:

```
plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.2"
    }
```

But the problem is: this plugin just loads the resource files when the most first request comes up, so it make the response of that request (in my situation is the login request) is too long. So is there any solution to force the resource plugin to run all its own necessary processes right after the application started, no need to wait for the first request?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Resources Plugin allows you to manage your resources in an efficient and modular way.  Meaning you can load resources that are required for each pages.  If your resources are taking too long maybe you are loading unnecessary css,js on your login page.

Couple approaches you can take:

- Optimize your resources. Use only what you need. In you SomethingResources.groovy, you can bundle your resources and load each bundle when needed. For example, required only css,js needed for login.
- Use `zipped-resources` and `cached-resources`, or  `yui-minify-resources` plugin. They help you to transfer or load resources faster.
- Resources plugin allows to load resources in different part of the page, sometimes loading js files at the end of the page, simulates a faster loading page. `disposition`

Btw, Resources plugin pre-process css, js files at the start of your application, however unless there is a request from the client browser, resources would not be transferred to client. Optimizing them help to ease this transition.

I hope this will help